# vim search for strings in bracket

Tags: vim, regex

I have bunch of strings like this:

```
[some_strings_in_square_bracket]$ some_strings_not_in ..
[some_strings_in_square_bracket]$ some_strings_not_in ..
[some_strings_in_square_bracket]$ some_strings_not_in ..
[some_strings_in_square_bracket]$ some_strings_not_in ..
[some_strings_in_square_bracket]$ some_strings_not_in ..
```

I want to remove everything in bracket plus the dollar sign and following whitespace.

I tried:

```
:g/\[.+?\]\$\s/d
```

but it says Pattern not found. regex is working in python:

```
>>> print x
[some_strings_in_square_bracket]$ some_strings_not_in ..
[some_strings_in_square_bracket]$ some_strings_not_in ..
[some_strings_in_square_bracket]$ some_strings_not_in ..
[some_strings_in_square_bracket]$ some_strings_not_in ..
[some_strings_in_square_bracket]$ some_strings_not_in ..

>>> print re.sub('\[.+?\]\$\s', '', x)
some_strings_not_in ..
some_strings_not_in ..
some_strings_not_in ..
some_strings_not_in ..
some_strings_not_in ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead it replaces the matched regex with nothing.

```
:%s/^\[.*\]\$\s\+//
```

Even if `:g/\[.+?\]\$\s/d` matched what you wanted the `d` at the end deletes the line not the matched regex.

As for why it doesn't match you need to escape the `+`. Vim treats that as a literal by default not as one or more.

Comment: thanks. vim regex is quite different from that of python.

Comment: @thkang take a look at `:h magic`. This mode escapes things in a more logical way if you know some other regex. But vim regex is its own flavor of regex

Comment: @thkang, actually, python's regex syntax is quite different from Vim's syntax.